# Xamarin Forms throw null exception when swipe left in the ListView and then select other item

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am using a ListView with the Delete context menu. The error occurs when the user swipes left to open the context menu and then select other item in the list view.

These are the details from HockeyApp crash report: exception **ArgumentNullException**, gesture **UIKit.UIView.RemoveGestureRecognizer**

Any idea?

---

Here is my current code:

Xam file:

```
<ListView 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" 
    RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" 
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="{Binding IsPullToRefreshEnabled}" 
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
    IsVisible="{Binding HasRecords}"
    HasUnevenRows="{Binding HasUnevenRows}">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
            </ViewCell.ContextActions>

            <local:DetailItemView />
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Xaml.cs file

```
void OnItemSelected (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        return; 

    VM.ItemSelected ((MyViewModel.DTO)e.SelectedItem);
    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; 
}

public void OnDelete (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);
    VM.ItemDelete ((MyViewModel.DTO)mi.CommandParameter);
}
```

HockeyApp Crash Report:

---

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'System.ArgumentNullException', reason: 'System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.'

Xamarin Exception Stack:
Parameter name: gestureRecognizer
  at UIKit.UIView.RemoveGestureRecognizer (UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer) <0x10026fd50 + 0x000b4> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextScrollViewDelegate.ClearCloserRecognizer (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) <0x100c4b480 + 0x0004b> in <34c8b4fc19184af1ae50594c101d8864#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextScrollViewDelegate+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0 () <0x100c7fe50 + 0x000c7> in <34c8b4fc19184af1ae50594c101d8864#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+ParameterlessDispatch.Activated () <0x100275db0 + 0x00023> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging:objc_msgSend (intptr,intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIView.RemoveGestureRecognizer (UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer gestureRecognizer) <0x10026fd50 + 0x0005b> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextScrollViewDelegate.ClearCloserRecognizer (UIKit.UIScrollView scrollView) <0x100c4b480 + 0x00073> in <34c8b4fc19184af1ae50594c101d8864#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ContextScrollViewDelegate+<>c__DisplayClass10_0.b__0 () <0x100c7fe50 + 0x000c7> in <34c8b4fc19184af1ae50594c101d8864#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer+ParameterlessDispatch.Activated () <0x100275db0 + 0x00023> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) <0x1002b5e10 + 0x0002b> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x1002b5d50 + 0x000ab> in <1b8eccd9010447b8b48086ab0847b072#0853931a0d4fb8314c38f588ee80ed00>:0 
  at MCA.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) <0x10023ed60 + 0x00037> in :0

Comment: Look at the following forum thread. This should be fixed in xforms 2.3.3.168-stable. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77956/xamarin-ios-10-bug-in-listview-context-menu-item

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with XF in iOS 10.2. I have updated XF to version 2.3.3.175 and it's working. thanks